# SQLITE Android delete query Executed but not Delete That value. It Shows again on APP launch

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, delete-row

**Here is My code**

```
public void deleteNote(String tv){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM TBT WHERE name='" + tv +"'");
    db.close();
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: No error or exeption query execute but value remain same

Comment: You are using cursor or ArrayList for list view..? if its ArrayList check whether you are deleting in your ArrayList.

Comment: i am using recyclerview on touchlistner Delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `db.delete`

```
public void deleteNote(String tv){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{tv});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
public Integer deleteProduct (String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(PRODUCT_TABLE_NAME,
                COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID +"=?", new String[]{id});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **`delete()`** method of **`SQLiteDatabase`** to delete the record from table try the below example.

```
// Deleting record
public void deleteNote(String tv) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{tv});
   db.close();
}
```